# RTX 2060 on Ubuntu 18.04, driver installed correctly but system is still using llvmpipe

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia

I got a RTX 2060 for Ubuntu 18.04 system and the nvidia driver (440.33.01) is installed successfully.
However, under about info for graphics I still got llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 256 bits).

```
~$ nvidia-smi
Mon May  4 02:04:18 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    On   | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 68%   65C    P2   111W / 170W |    724MiB /  5926MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:86 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:92000000-9207ffff
```

Also in Software & Updates, I could not choose Bvidia driver in additional drivers at first (the option was grey). After adding nvidia-drm.modeset=1 to the grub, I was able to choose Nvidia driver but the system doesn't allow me to apply the changes.

Does anyone know how to enable the Nvidia driver for the Ubuntu?

[image: driver list]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to select it here:

**Show Applications** gnome menu -> Enter into **Search** field **Additional** keyword and open **Additional Drivers** (opened tab in **Software & Updates** window will appear). Look if there's the nvidia-drivers present and select the point if not selected.

Comment: Hi, I did try to select the nvidia-drivers in Additional Drivers tab. But after I applied changes, the system chose Nouveau by itself.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling nvidia driver, it works. Not sure what happen at the begining.